# Wrong link on Ask a Question page in Teams

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

> [image]

- Wrong link: http://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000042856-asking-a-question
- Correct link: https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4385980-ask-a-question

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome and Firefox

Comment: I think calling it a broken link is a little misleading. It's simply a link that leads somewhere completely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link has been fixed. It now goes to https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4385980-ask-a-question